# Find the Dimension of $W=\operatorname{span}\{I,A,A^2,A^3,\ldots,A^m,\ldots\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

> Let $A \in M^{\Bbb C}_{n \times n}$ be a square matrix with a **minimal polynomial** of the degree $k$.
>
> Find the dimension of  $W=\operatorname{span} \{ I, A, A^2, A^3, \ldots, A^m, \ldots\}$
>
> The question assumes **finite dimension**.

I think I have to use induction here.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: What do you mean by "span is independent"? If all the elements over which the span is taken are independent then the dimension is, by definition, infinite, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Vossler edited my question, thank you.

Comment: What do you know about minimal polynomials?  If $f(x)$ is a minimal polynomial, what's $f(M)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need finite dimension of the vector space acted upon, the existence of a minimal polynomial for the linear operator (I'll call it $T$) suffices (but of course finite dimension does imply this existence, whereas in infinite dimension no minimal polynomial is guaranteed to exist).

Having a linear relation $\sum_{i=0}^dc_iT^d=0$ is precisely saying that the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^dc_iX^d$ annihilates$~T$, so the fact that $T$ has a minimal polynomial of degree$~k$ means that the family $[T^0,\ldots,T^{k-1}]$ is linearly independent, while the family $[T^0,\ldots,T^k]$ is linearly dependent, which must be because $T^k\in W$ where $\def\Span{\operatorname{Span}}W=\Span(T^0,\ldots,T^{k-1})$. The former means that $\dim W=k$, while the latter means the subspace $W$ is $T$-stable (because $T$ sends each of the generators to a vector of$~W$). But then clearly $T^m\in W$ for all$~m\in\Bbb N$, so that $W=\Span(T^0,\ldots,T^k,\ldots)$, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

If $m(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k a_ix^i$ is the minimal, then $m(A)=0$. Now, I affirm that $A^{k}\in \text{span}\{I, ..., A^{k-1}\}$, because $A^k=-1/a_k \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_iA^i$

Comment: This proves that $A^k$ is linearly dependent with the first k powers of $A$. What about the other elements of the span?

Comment: Multiply by A and obtain that all are in this span

Comment: Yes, you can make this work by extending the argument, but this is not present in your proof.

Comment: @Vossler Pedantry on obvious points is obnoxious.

Comment: @StellaBiderman The exact same point can be used to justify that the single word "Obvious" is also a valid answer here, since the answer to the question is a pretty obvious consequence of the definition.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I also consider the word "obnoxious" to be quite offensive in a maths-related discussion.

Comment: @Vossler I'm sorry that you find that quite offensive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which will hopefully function as a hint.  Suppose that $A^2+3A+6I=0$, so that $A^2=-3A-6I$.  Then $A^3=A(A^2)=-3A^2-6A=-3(-3A-6I)-6A$.  Similarly, we multiplying this by $A$ and rewriting, we could express $A^4$ as a linear combination of $A$ and $I$.  Now, use induction.  Now, generalize.  This should hint you at what the answer is (and prove one direction of it).

Answer (score 0):

$\text{dim}W=k$ (well, if k>0).

Since the minimal polynomial of $A$ has the degree k, it means that there exist $a_i,i=0...k$:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^ka_iA^i=0.
$$
Moreover, $a_k\neq{0}$.

Can you now prove yourself that there exists a linear combination of any $k+1$ powers of $A$ equal to zero?

Since the polynomial is **minimal**, no lower-degree linear dependency is possible.